# C# Sorting list by another list

Tags: c#, sorting

I have now 2 lists:

```
list<string> names;
list<int> numbers;
```

and I need to sort my names based on the values in numbers.
I've been searching, and most use something like x.ID, but i don't really know what that value is. So that didn't work.

Does anyone know, what to do, or can help me out in the ID part?

Comment: Why do you need two lists for one information? Use a `Dictionary<int,string>` instead.

Comment: @TimSchmelter An ordinary `Dictionary<,>` will not be sorted by keys (it uses hash codes). It sounds like a `SortedDictionary<int, string>` or `SortedList<int, string>` even more. I supplied an answer describing how to convert two lists into that.

Answer (score 8):

So i assume that the elements in both lists are related through the index.

```
names.Select((n, index) => new { Name = n, Index = index })
     .OrderBy(x => numbers.ElementAtOrDefault(x.Index))
     .Select(x => x.Name)
     .ToList();
```

But i would  use another collection type like `Dictionary<int,string>` instead if both lists are related insomuch.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this is a task for the `Zip` method. Something like

```
names.Zip(numbers, (name, number) => new { name, number, })
```

will "zip" the two sequences into one. From there you can either order the sequence immediately, like

```
.OrderBy(a => a.number)
```

or you can instead create a `Dictionary<,>`, like

```
.ToDictionary(a => a.number, a => a.name)
```

But it sounds like what you really want is a **`SortedDictionary<,>`**, not a `Dictionary<,>` which is organized by hash codes. There's no LINQ method for creating a sorted dictionary, but just say

```
var sorted = new SortedDictionary<int, string>();
foreach (var a in zipResultSequence)
    sorted.Add(a.number, a.name);
```

Or alternatively, with a `SortedDictionary<,>`, skip Linq entirely, an go like:

```
var sorted = new SortedDictionary<int, string>();
for (int idx = 0; idx < numbers.Count; ++idx)  // supposing the two list have same Count
    sorted.Add(numbers[idx], names[idx]);
```

Answer (score 0):

To complement Tims answer, you can also use a custom data structure to associate one name with a number.

```
public class Person
{
    public int Number { get; set; }   // in this case you could also name it ID
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Then you would have a `List<Person> persons;` and you can sort this List by whatever Attribute you like:

```
List<Person> persons = new List<Person>();
persons.Add(new Person(){Number = 10, Name = "John Doe"});
persons.Add(new Person(){Number = 3, Name = "Max Muster"});

// sort by number
persons = persons.OrderBy(p=>p.Number).ToList();

// alternative sorting method
persons.Sort((a,b) => a.Number-b.Number);
```

Comment: Thanks, but the string list, is in fact already a class, but for easy questioning I changed it for an string ^^

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by doing it with an dictionary, this was the result:

```
dictionary.OrderBy(kv => kv.Value).Reverse().Select(kv => kv.Key).ToList();
```

Comment: Use `OrderByDescending`instead of reversing after Ordering.